# jq to extract specific data with different map name of same type

Tags: json, api, jq, vault

I'm performing a query on vault API to list all the entities by their Ids and trying extract alias name from `aliases.name`, however, due to the different map name in each iteration I'm not able to extract the value.

**Command**

```
curl -s --header "X-Vault-Token: $TOKEN" --request LIST http://localhost:8200/v1/identity/entity/id | jq ".data.key_info"
```

**Result**

```
{
  "923104b3-910c-05b1-b448-fcg3d67276e1": {
    "aliases": [
      {
        "id": "6a6f2dc4-2cd8-1881-662f-b5955e765e0d",
        "mount_accessor": "auth_oidc_053b2418",
        "mount_path": "auth/oidc/",
        "mount_type": "oidc",
        "name": "John Doe"
      }
    ],
    "name": "entity_402ea123"
  },
  "ba6b00c4-36gg-gd86-86bf-13d731588241": {
    "aliases": [
      {
        "id": "3ji408b2-4548-75f7-8c41-9901b77af7d1",
        "mount_accessor": "auth_oidc_053b2418",
        "mount_path": "auth/oidc/",
        "mount_type": "oidc",
        "name": "Jane Smith"
      }
    ],
    "name": "entity_98746ae4"
  }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
"name": "John Doe"
"name": "Jane Smith"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to extract a stream of ojects with just the `name` field:

```sh
… | jq -c ".data.key_info[] | .aliases[] | {name}"
```

```json
{"name":"John Doe"}
{"name":"Jane Smith"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tOnsxMqvFF)

If you are trying to extract them as an array, use `map`:

```sh
… | jq ".data.key_info | map(.aliases[] | {name})"
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jane Smith"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mcyiPRRAX8)

If you just need the values, use the `-r` option:

```sh
… | jq -r ".data.key_info[].aliases[].name"
```

```
John Doe
Jane Smith
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AnGIQ9KVA2)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, thats exactly what i was looking for. appreciate your help.